# Let’s Encrypt で SSL証明書を自動更新したいのですが、cron設定する際のcertbotのパス指定について

Tags: centos, ssl, letsencrypt

**現状**
・[リンク](https://certbot.eff.org/#centosrhel7-nginx)の通り進めています

```
sudo yum install certbot-nginx
```

・cerbot がどこへインストールされたか分からないので調べているのですが、

```
ls /usr/bin/
```

> certbot -> /usr/bin/certbot-2
>    certbot-2

---

**予定**
・「/etc/cron.d/」の下にhogeファイル配置

---

**環境**
・CentOS7
・Nginx
・Let’s Encrypt
・certbot

---

**Q1**
・リンク先のcronジョブ例では「&& certbot renew」と記載されていますが、パスを記載する必要はない？

**Q2**
・certbotはどこにインストールされているのでしょうか？
・「certbot -> /usr/bin/certbot-2」はシンボリックリンク？

**Q3**
・「/etc/cron.d/hoge」でcertbotのパスを記載するとしたら

```
0 1 * * * /usr/bin/certbot renew && systemctl restart nginx
```

あるいは、下記？？

```
0 1 * * * /usr/bin/certbot-2 renew && systemctl restart nginx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1

フルパスを記述するか、/etc/cron.d/hoge ファイルにPATHを記述すればいいと思います。
例）

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin  ←コマンドサーチパスを「:」区切りで複数かけます
MAILTO=root
0 1 * * * root /usr/bin/certbot renew && systemctl restart nginx
```

> Q2

`/usr/bin/certbot` にインストールされてます。
`/usr/bin/certbot` はシンボリックリンクで、実体は `/usr/bin/certbot-2` という意味です。

パッケージの中身は rpm コマンドで確認できます。

```
$ rpm -ql certbot-nginx
```

> Q3

`/usr/bin/certbot` で良いと思います。

あと、/etc/cron.d/ の下のファイルは、実行ユーザを書く必要があるので、次の形式で書いて下さい。

```
.---------------- minute (0 - 59)
|  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
|  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
|  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
|  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
|  |  |  |  |
*  *  *  *  * user-name  command to be executed
```

Comment: 「/etc/cron.d/ の下のファイルは、実行ユーザを書く必要がある」。アドバイスありがとうございました。大変参考になりました